# Modify tensorflow android's DetectorActivity.java file to use retrain model, but the app crash

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

I follow the doc of https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/image_retraining/ retrain the model, then put the output_graph.pb and output_labels.txt files to android assets directory.

I modify this ClassifierActivity.java and it works well. But I modify this DetectorActivity.java https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/19d932f4cb49182c111d646267ac6c0bbc4f2f00/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/DetectorActivity.java#L55-L62 , it will crash on starting `TF Detect` app.

The file diff is this:

```java
--- a/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/DetectorActivity.java
+++ b/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/DetectorActivity.java
@@ -53,14 +53,14 @@ public class DetectorActivity extends CameraActivity implements OnImageAvailable

   // Configuration values for the prepackaged multibox model.
   private static final int MB_NUM_LOCATIONS = 784;
-  private static final int MB_INPUT_SIZE = 224;
+  private static final int MB_INPUT_SIZE = 299;
   private static final int MB_IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
   private static final float MB_IMAGE_STD = 128;
-  private static final String MB_INPUT_NAME = "ResizeBilinear";
-  private static final String MB_OUTPUT_NAMES = "output_locations/Reshape,output_scores/Reshape";
-  private static final String MB_MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/multibox_model.pb";
+  private static final String MB_INPUT_NAME = "Mul:0";
+  private static final String MB_OUTPUT_NAMES = "final_result:0";
+  private static final String MB_MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/output_graph.pb";
   private static final String MB_LOCATION_FILE =
-      "file:///android_asset/multibox_location_priors.txt";
+      "file:///android_asset/output_labels.txt";

   // Configuration values for tiny-yolo-voc. Note that the graph is not included with TensorFlow and
```

this is crash logs:

```
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Adding size: 640x480
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Not adding size: 320x240
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Adding size: 1280x720
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Adding size: 1920x1080
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Adding size: 1280x960
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Adding size: 1440x1080
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Not adding size: 208x144
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Not adding size: 176x144
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Not adding size: 352x288
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Adding size: 960x544
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Adding size: 960x720
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Adding size: 720x720
02-04 13:53:15.104 24989 24989 I tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Chosen size: 640x480
02-04 13:53:15.185   991  8492 E ReportTools: This is not beta user build
02-04 13:53:15.296   991  1272 E InputDispatcher: channel 'c5e551d org.tensorflow.demo/org.tensorflow.demo.DetectorActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-04 13:53:15.300   991  2443 E HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
02-04 13:53:15.309  2828  2957 E PackageLogInfoManager: checkPackageLogState, cr: android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver@4458425, packageNames: null
```

Comment: (1) Post the crash logs! (2) what is the meaning of `:0` in the input and output names?

Comment: @GrishaLevit added logs. `:0` exists in ClassifierActivity.java, so I think there is a need here? Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: DetectorActivity doesn't work with Inception models -- it requires a special MultiBox model. We'll have code/instructions for retraining that at some point in the future.

Comment: @AndrewHarp Thank you for your reply, probably what time?